# Why does $'\141' convert to ASCII 'a' as expected, but constructing the same string doesn't convert?

Tags: bash, shell, ascii

```
#!/bin/bash
$'\141'

string1="$'\\"
number=141
string2="'"
result="${string1}${number}${string2}"
$result
```

Running this script gives this response:

```
./temp.sh: line 2: a: command not found
./temp.sh: line 8: $'\141': command not found
```

Why are these two not equivalent? What would need to be changed in the second attempt to get the correct ASCII conversion?

Clearly the second try isn't being converted to 'a' as expected. Why is this? I thought maybe because I escaped the special meaning of backslash by doing `\\`. But if that's the case, does it mean it's not possible to do this ASCII conversion on a constructed string?

For additional information, this is for a CTF where I must run `cat ../../flag` or equivalent without using any letters. So I'm trying to use an ASCII conversion.

Comment: `Why are these two not equivalent?` - because [that's how it works in all programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57977776/11683), and it would be impossible to generate or process text inputs if it was otherwise.

Comment: Because the shell parses quotes, escapes, etc *before* expanding variables, so putting quotes (including the `$'...'` quote style) into a variable doesn't do anything useful. At a more basic level, variables contain *data*, not shell syntax, so if you put `$'...'` in a variable, it'll be treated as data, not parsed as shell syntax. See ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)

Comment: @GordonDavisson ahh I see - so I suppose what I'm trying to do is impossible since $'variable' will not resolve the variable and it would take the literal word variable

Answer (score 1):

From the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

> ### 3.1.2.2 Single Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes (`'`) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> ### 3.1.2.3 Double Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes (`"`) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, *[...]*. The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: `$`, `` ` ``, `"`, `\`, or <kbd>newline</kbd>. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified. *[...]*
>
> ### 3.1.2.4 ANSI-C Quoting
>
> Character sequences of the form `$’string’` are treated as a special kind of single quotes. The sequence expands to `string`, with backslash-escaped characters in `string` replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard. Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded *[...]*
>
> **The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.**

Emphasis mine.

Note that the backslash escape sequences allowed in ANSI-C quoting are not defined in double-quoted strings. As described in 3.1.2.3, backslashes in double-quoted strings have a different use/meaning.

Comment: ok this makes sense. so i guess what I'm trying to do is impossible since the expected syntax is this: $'\141' and inside the 'single quotes' is ANSI-C quoting. meaning that I cannot put a variable inside like $'VARIABLE'.
And would need to use an alt method like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235651/how-can-i-do-ansi-c-quoting-of-an-existing-bash-variable

Answer (score 0):

If you have error, it's simply a syntax error.

What you need to construct `ASCII` letters from variables:

```
i=141; printf '%b\n' '\'$i
a
```

or to construct from multiple variables (only 2 needed):

```
start='\' number=141; printf '%b\n' "$start$number"
a
```

---

From `POSIX` Open Group:

> The `%b` conversion specification is not part of the ISO C standard; it has been added here as **a portable way to process -escapes** expanded in string operands as provided by the `echo` utility. See also the APPLICATION USAGE section of echo for ways to use `printf` as a replacement for all of the traditional versions of the `echo` utility.

See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html

Comment: I believe the OP is asking why the character escaping rules apply to string literals and do not apply to contents of string variables.